# ArgumentError (missing required option :name)

Tags: amazon-s3, carrierwave, ruby-on-rails-6

I have deployed to Heroku a basic gallery website but the image upload functionality in not working, it gives me 500 Internal Server Error, it all works on the local server. I am using AWS S3 bucket for storage.

### My Uploader file

```
class PortfolioUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  storage :aws

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  # def default_url(*args)
  #   # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  #   # ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
  #
  #   "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  # end
  def extension_whitelist
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end
end
```

---

controller file create method

```
  def create
    @portfolio_item = Portfolio.new(portfolio_params)
    if @portfolio_item.save
      redirect_to portfolios_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------carrierwave.rb file

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.storage    = :aws
  config.aws_bucket = ENV.fetch('S3_BUCKET_NAME') # for AWS-side bucket access permissions config, see section below
  config.aws_acl    = 'private'
  config.aws_authenticated_url_expiration = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
  config.aws_attributes = -> { {
    expires: 1.week.from_now.httpdate,
    cache_control: 'max-age=604800'
  } }

  config.aws_credentials = {
    access_key_id:     ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
    secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
    region:            ENV.fetch('AWS_REGION'), # Required
    stub_responses:    Rails.env.test? # Optional, avoid hitting S3 actual during tests
  }
end
```

---

````
2020-11-05T10:35:32.467646+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2020-11-05T10:35:32.467563 #4] FATAL -- : [421e9f92-f540-4552-aa31-be18534786e4]
2020-11-05T10:35:32.467647+00:00 app[web.1]: [421e9f92-f540-4552-aa31-be18534786e4] ArgumentError (missing required option :name):
2020-11-05T10:35:32.467648+00:00 app[web.1]: [421e9f92-f540-4552-aa31-be18534786e4]
2020-11-05T10:35:32.467648+00:00 app[web.1]: [421e9f92-f540-4552-aa31-be18534786e4] app/controllers/portfolios_controller.rb:26:in `create'```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like when you call portfolio_params you are not passing in name which is a required field to create a portfolio.

Can you share a params example when entering the create method as well as your portfolio_params method from the controller?